# Encrypt using Fernet in Django and Decrypt in PHP - Error Decryption failed

Tags: php, django

I'm required to Decrypt value from DB in php, but the value Encrypt in Django using Fernet. I tried something but it doesn't work. I getting this error message Decryption failed: error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length

Here what i have tried

```
$encryption_key = Using same key from django;

$ekyc = Wallet::find('1');

        $value= $ekyc->address;

        $decodedData = base64_decode(strtr($value, '-_', '+/'));

        echo "Decoded Data: " . bin2hex($decodedData) . "<br>";

        // Extract the initialization vector (IV) and ciphertext
        $ivSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-128-cbc');
        $iv = substr($decodedData, 0, $ivSize);
        $ciphertext = substr($decodedData, $ivSize);

        echo "IV: " . bin2hex($iv) . "<br>";

        // Replace 'aes-128-cbc' with the appropriate cipher and mode if needed
        $decrypted_data = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'aes-128-cbc', $encryption_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);


        if ($decrypted_data === false) {
            die('Decryption failed: ' . openssl_error_string());
        }
        dd($decrypted_data);
```

I'm expected to get the decrypted value. Can please advice what is wrong and how can i solve this? Thank you so much

Comment: Does this help? https://packagist.org/packages/kelvinmo/fernet-php

Comment: @AmooAti. its the same. im getting the null value even using the same encrypt key

Comment: Welp.it works.need to get correct value from table.thanks